# "Sorry, this page could not be found."

Tags: instagram

I have one website, and i use the Intagram API.

But, since morning, after user login (or authorize the app), the page show the result:
"Sorry, this page could not be found."

But, my page is ok. And, if i enter again in this page. The Instagram redirect to my page correctly.

I don't know what is it. And why Instagram not redirect automatic.

Comment: Instead of redirecting the user after login, make your page display the redirection link as an href and see what broke your code. Other than that it'll take a psychic to guess what's wrong with your code - but if you'd post the relevant parts...

Comment: I got this: `{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered             redirect URI"}`

Comment: The new url doesn't work one the 1st, 2nd and 3rd attempts...

Comment: But the error "Sorry, this page could not be found."
This error is from Instagram. And the Instagram not redirect to my page.

If you put token (https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=30d4925e038f42b4a08b357ed37c7244&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Finstalikes.com.br%2Fsucess.php&response_type=token&scope=likes+relationships), you accept my app and go to the link (https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=30d4925e038f42b4a08b357ed37c7244&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Finstalikes.com.br%2Fsucess.php&response_type=code&scope=likes+relationships) again. The page will work.

Comment: I do not know why, but Instagram don't redirect to my page.

But I discovered a interesting thing.

I changed the url to redirect to another domain. And then I changed the. Htacess to 'redirect' to the url of the official website.

And it worked! Apparently Instagram bloqueiou my website (at least the url).
But not yet a fix for the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Domain was banned in the Client ID